# What is the antonym of "result" or "consequence"?

Tags: antonyms

A "result" or "consequence" is the what happens as a result of the concept of the word. For example: War -- death, suffering, winner, looser, etc. Is there a word that can describe the opposite meaning of the result of a concept? Perhaps an antonym for "result" or "consequence"?

Comment: Thank you Elliott sometimes the obvious is out of reach; my mind is suffering from tunnel vision. What I might have been looking for is, in the War example, the opposite effects. I think upshot is getting close to that. Not quite Peace, but its causes.

Comment: The opposite is nothing at all.  Or everything.

Comment: We need an example.  What is something that is not the result of losing?

Comment: If war leads to death and death is a "result", then by opposite of "result" do you mean a word for the thing(s) that lead to war? Or for the thing(s) that war does *not* lead to? Or for...?

Answer (score 4):

The *cause* (with *result* being synonymous with *effect*).

Merriam-Webster defines *cause* as,

> [**cause**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cause)   *noun*
>
> : something or someone that produces an effect, result, or condition : something or someone that makes something happen or exist

It further lists, the following (bold added for emphasis) -

> **Antonyms**
>           aftereffect, aftermath, **consequence**, corollary, development, effect, fate, fruit, issue, outcome, outgrowth, product, **result**, resultant, sequel, sequence, upshot

Answer (score 3):

The word **antecedent** works well here.  From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/antecedent?s=t) -

> adjective
>
> 1. preceding; prior:
>
>    - an antecedent event.
>
> noun
>
> 2. a preceding circumstance, event, object, style, phenomenon, etc.